# Finding a match between array and database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array called "selected_checkboxes". In my database I have multiple columns and some of them contain the value `1`, otherwise the value will be `NULL`. The names of those columns are exactly the same as the values of the array.

I would now like to check dynamically if the values of my array (`$_POST['selected_checkboxes']`) match with the values of my columns in the database. If ALL values from the array have the value 1 in the database, it should echo something like **Match!**

This is what I have tried so far but I think it's completely wrong:

```
if(!$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products")){
     die('Error');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    foreach($_POST['selected_checkboxes'] as $value) {
        if ($value == 1) {
            $say .= $value . ' is = 1';
        }
    }
}
echo $say;
```

I appreciate any help!!

**Edit:**

This is how the array 'selected_checkboxes' is getting generated:

```
$('.show_result').click(function() {    
    // Get all selected checkboxes
    var selected = [];
    $.each($("input[type=checkbox]:checked"), function(){            
         selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    // Get the selected option field
    selected.push($('#PG_Select_Bereich1').val());

    // Deliver data to PHP
    $.ajax({
         url : "typo3conf/ext/produkteguide_sg/pi1/products.php",
         type: "POST",
         data : { selected_checkboxes:selected },
         success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
         {
              $("#PG_Resultate").html(data);
         },
         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
         {
             //alert(errorThrown);
         }
    });
```

And this is how my database looks like: 
[image]

Comment: Please provide your DB structure and array so, it clarifies more.

Comment: Checkbox sends `[checkbox_name] => on` if checked, and nothing if unchecked. So you should check for 'on' string, not '1'. Checking with `isset($_POST['checkbox_name'])` is even better since its value is constant.

Comment: Is `isset($_POST['checkbox_name'])` an array of checkbox?

Comment: @sandeepsure I have updated my post. Please see the edits.

Comment: @AlanMachado $_POST['selected_checkboxes'] returns the value of the checkboxes. It's a JS behind it. Please see my edits above.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar but in a different way, I hope this is what you're looking for:

```
// Query execution
$result = mysqli_query($CONN,"SELECT * FROM whatever");

while($row_from_db = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $db_value = is_null($row_from_db['myValue']) ? 0 : 1;
    $check_value = !isset($_POST['selected_checkboxes']['myValue']) ? 0 : 1

    echo $db_value == $check_value ? "Match!" : "Not matching :(";
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the thing is that I do not know which checkbox is getting clicked. So there is no way for me to type a value as I see in your code "myValue". There must be a dynamic way I guess.

Comment: `isset($_POST['selected_checkboxes']['myValue'])` checks if that specific checkbox is checked... if null value is returned, the checkbox has not been clicked

Answer (score 0):

I am writing pseudo code for your requirement.

1) loop through array.

2) while loop through array if value of element is found 1 the go to next step otherwise continue loop.

3) If array element value is 1 then get a key of element and prepare sql query which checks that column name same as key name have value as 1 for each record then mark it as Match.

Hope this helps to you. If you not get with this then let me know i will write the code for you.

**Edit:**
Each of your checkbox name must be same as column name in database.

```
 $array_checkbox = $_POST['selected_checkboxes'];
 $query =" SELECT count(*) FROM <tabel_name> WHERE 1=1";
 // get count from query and store it in $total_rows variable
 $total_rows = 10;  // for example purpose we take count value as 10

 foreach($array_checkbox as $key => $checkbox){
     $query =  $query =" SELECT count(*) FROM <tabel_name> WHERE $key=1"; // here we take key of array as column name in sql query and getting that how many rows of the column have value 1

 // get count from query and store it in $result variable
     $result = 10;
     if($result == $total_rows){
         echo "Match";
     }
 }
```

Hope this is according to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you. Step 1 is clear to me but step 2 starts to get complicated. What I don't understand is how to loop through 2 arrays at the same time (selected checkboxes & database query). If you could help me out with some code, I would really appreciate it.